# How to work with Tooltips using same ID or class name?

Tags: html, onclick, jquery-selectors, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am creating a page with ~50 lines where single click on a line will copy that line. And there's a tooltip for **copy** (*on hover*) & **copied** (*on click*).

Using the below code, I am able to copy each line with single click. And the **copy** tooltip also shows up on hover.
But the "**copied**" tooltip is working only for first line. It's not working for the rest because of same id & I cannot give each line a different id.

How to solve this using same ID or class name?

```js
         var copy = document.querySelectorAll(".copy");
         
         for (const copied of copy) {
             copied.onclick = function () {
                 document.execCommand("copy");
                 var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
                 tooltip.innerHTML = "Copied!";
             };
         
             copied.onmouseover = function () {
                 var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
                 tooltip.innerHTML = "Copy";
             };
         
             copied.addEventListener("copy", function (event) {
                 event.preventDefault();
                 if (event.clipboardData) {
                     event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", copied.textContent);
                     console.log(event.clipboardData.getData("text"));
                 }
             });
         }
```

```css
         .tooltip {
         position: relative;
         display: inline-block;
         }
         .tooltip .tooltiptext {
         visibility: hidden;
         background: red;
         color: #fff;
         text-align: center;
         padding: 3px 3px;
         border-radius: 15px;
         position: absolute;
         z-index: 1;
         bottom: 90%;
         left: 75%;
         opacity: 0;
         transition: opacity 0.3s;
         }
         .tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
         content: "";
         position: absolute;
         top: 100%;
         left: 50%;
         margin-left: -5px;
         border-width: 5px;
         border-style: solid;
         border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
         }
         .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
         visibility: visible;
         opacity: 1;
         }
         .copy {
         cursor: pointer;
         }
```

```html
<html>
   <body style="text-align: center;">
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="tooltip">
         <p class="copy">Copy this 1st line.</p>
         <span class="tooltiptext" id="myTooltip">Copy</span>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="tooltip">
         <p class="copy">Copy this 2nd line.</p>
         <span class="tooltiptext" id="myTooltip">Copy</span>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="tooltip">
         <p class="copy">Copy this 3rd line.</p>
         <span class="tooltiptext" id="myTooltip">Copy</span>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="tooltip">
         <p class="copy">Copy this 4th line.</p>
         <span class="tooltiptext" id="myTooltip">Copy</span>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Once try with using title attribute on that particular element .
i.e `<div title="Copy this 4th line.">
         <span>Copy</span>
      </div>`